# Prolog Higher-order reduce predicate

Tags: prolog, higher-order-functions, meta-predicate

We can define a higher-order *map* predicate as:

```
map([], [], F).
map([A|As], [B|Bs], F) :-
   call(F, A, B),
   map(As, Bs, F).
```

Similarly, we can define *fold* (left) as:

```
fold([], Acc, Acc, _F).
fold([A|As], B, Acc1, F) :-
   call(F, Acc1, A, Acc2),
   fold(As, B, Acc2, F).
```

What is the correct definition for *reduce* (left)? Can we define it as follows?

```
reduce([A|As], Bs, F) :-   
   fold(As, Bs, A, F).
```

And *reduceback* (right) as follows?

```
reduceback([], Ident, F) :-
   identity(F, Ident).
reduceback([A|As], B, F) :-
   reduceback(As, C, F),
   call(F, C, A, B).
```

Are these correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fold/4 and reduce/3 perform correctly, while without identity/1 reduceback/3 is incomplete. But the control flow seems correct, though

```
1 ?- fold([1,2,3],S,0,[X,Y,Z]>>(Z is X+Y)).
S = 6.

2 ?- reduce([1,2,3],S,[X,Y,Z]>>(Z is X+Y)).
S = 6.
```

I've added the declarations

```
:- meta_predicate fold(+,?,+,3).
:- meta_predicate reduce(+,?,3).
```

that qualify arguments as closures, and used library([yall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)) for lambdas...

In Prolog, a common convention is to place output arguments as last, so your definitions are rather unreadable to me....

*edit*

for symmetry with reduce/3, identity/1 seems useless, the last element could be used instead: so it could be

```
:- meta_predicate reduceback(+,?,3).

reduceback([Last],Last,_F).
reduceback([A|As],B,F):-
  reduceback(As,C,F),
  call(F,C,A,B).
```

test:

```
?- reduceback([1,2,3],S,[X,Y,Z]>>(Z is X+Y)).
S = 6 ;
false.

?- reduceback([1,2,3],S,[X,Y,Z]>>(Z is X-Y)).
S = 0 ;
false.
```